# how to replace \ or / with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

How to replace / or \ in text file?
I have tried to 'escape' these characters but with no success so far

echo '/// \\' | sed 's////some_text/'

will obviously not work.

thanks
BM

Answer (score 6):

`echo "\\\message\//" |  sed 's;[\/];REPLACEMENT-TEXT;g'`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change delimiter then this

`sed 's/[\\/]/U/g' temp.txt`